# Potential uninitialized access in zlib

Tags: c

The [zlib library](http://www.zlib.net) is a venerable piece of C software. The copyright for the decompression routine goes back to 1995, with the last rewrite in 2002. It is used daily by millions.

To be perfect, the decompression routine should not invoke undefined behavior, even if passed a maliciously crafted buffer. I have the opportunity to detect a number of places where it is not obvious that the library does not invoke undefined behavior on some input. Would users of this site help me in confirming these issues? We would improve an already great piece of Open Source software, and there is always something to learn in reading code that has passed the test of time.

Assuming this is okay, for my first post, I would like to suggest looking at function `inflate()` in version 1.2.7 of the library.

```
int ZEXPORT inflate(strm, flush)
z_streamp strm;
int flush;
{
    struct inflate_state FAR *state;
    state = (struct inflate_state FAR *)strm->state;
/*** strm->state was previously allocated with malloc(), apparently.
Function malloc(), when it succeeds,
returns an uninitialized block of memory. */
...
    for (;;)
        switch (state->mode) {
...
        case MATCH:
            if (left == 0) goto inf_leave;
            copy = out - left;
            if (state->offset > copy) {         /* copy from window */
/*** It is unclear if state->offset always contains initialized contents 
at this point, line 1125 in inflate.c.
*/
...
```

So my question is, is it possible to reach line 1125 in inflate.c without having initialized `state->offset`?

I linked the library with the following `main()` function to identify the possible issue, so I guess that an input vector, if one exists, could be based on this `main()`, simply initializing array `in[]` to values that cause the issue. This `main()` is using the library correctly, I hope, otherwise the flagged issue may be meaningless.

```
#include "zlib.h"

#define CHUNK 100

z_stream strm;
unsigned char in[CHUNK];
unsigned char out[CHUNK];
int ret;

main(){
  int i;

  /* allocate inflate state */
  strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
  strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
  strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
  strm.avail_in = 0;
  strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
  ret = inflateInit(&strm);
  if (ret != Z_OK)
    return ret;

  for (i=0; i<CHUNK; i++)
    in[i] = any();

  strm.next_in = in;
  strm.avail_in = CHUNK;
  strm.next_out = out;
  strm.avail_out = CHUNK;

  ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
}
```

Of course, if the apparently dangerous access at line 1125 is in fact safe, then a great answer would be an explanation why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert in the `zlib` source tree nor am I familiar with the coding style of its authors, but I found this to be an interesting question.  I'd say <s>it looks safe and</s> my guess is the original authors are expecting `offset` to be initialized to zero. **Update:** OK, I misread an `if` statement; looking at it again it looks like it might be unsafe without a custom allocator, so we'd have to look at `inflateInit` et al. and the actual inflate logic to know for sure.

Explanation follows:

It looks like `inflate_state` is allocated with the `ZALLOC` macro.

That macro resolves to:

```
#define ZALLOC(strm, items, size) \
       (*((strm)->zalloc))((strm)->opaque, (items), (size))
```

According to comments in `zlib.h`, correct use of the library requires the caller to initialize the `zalloc` member being called:

> The application must initialize zalloc, zfree and opaque before
>    calling the init function.

If `strm->zalloc` is `NULL`, which I'd expect most callers to do, the library uses its own default implementation, `zcalloc`.

<s>`zcalloc`, with some exceptions for ancient MS-DOS compilers and so long as `sizeof(unsigned int)` is greater than 1, ends up calling `calloc`.</s>

`calloc` by definition zeroes out its data.

So, I'd say it's safe under the following conditions:

1. If you use a custom allocator, make sure it zeroes out the data.

<s>2. `sizeof(unsigned int)` must be > 1.  (I'm guessing the standard guarantees that but I'm not certain.)</s>

**After the update:** Now realizing that the allocations are not necessarily zeroed, I'd say it all depends on whether or not the local variable `here` can be used uninitialized, as the only assignment I see is based on that value.

Note that `inflateInit`, which calls `inflateReset`, which calls `inflateResetKeep`, seems to initialize the members that the assignments to `here` depends on, notably `lenbits`.  It looks like there are lots of size checks for overflow as well, eg: `if ((unsigned)(here.bits) <= bits) break;`.  I haven't given it a thorough audit but I'd say everything I've seen so far looks safe.

Comment: When I analyzed it, I got this call stack: malloc <- zcalloc <- inflateInit2_ <- inflateInit_ <- main. I had to provide `malloc()`, and I provided an allocation function that does not initialize (since `malloc()` doesn't. Let me investigate and come back to you.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Set it to `NULL` and you should be fine.

Comment: I set `strm.zalloc` to `NULL` (see the `main()`) in my question). You must be referring to `sizeof(uInt) > 2 ? (voidpf)malloc(items * size) : (voidpf)calloc(items, size)` in zutil.c:310. This resolves to a call to `malloc()` on many architectures, including the one my analysis is tuned for (`sizeof(uInt)==4`).

Comment: @PascalCuoq - Yeah I looked back and it and it was backwards from how I read it the first time.  Whoops.

Comment: Yes, the only assignment to `state->offset` is from `here` at line inflate.c:1103. The way I see the question is, if it possible to craft an input where `case MATCH:` is taken before `case DIST:`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq - Doesn't look like it.  The only `state->mode = MATCH;` line comes from the `DISTEXT` state which can only come from `DIST`.

Comment: Well solved. Meanwhile, I have confirmed that the analyzer's worry is not that `state->offset` might be assigned the contents of an uninitialized `here`, but that the sequence might be wrong (the thing you just pointed out cannot happen). I will have to force it to track `state->mode` more carefully to avoid more false positives of the same vein.